# Confirmation Email will not send

Tags: php, forms, email

So i have this contact form, everything sends fine after the submit button is pressed. However the confirmation email does not seem to send...

I couldnt find the answer on here anywhere, or i would not have asked

The Confirmation email code

```
<?php
$your_email = "jp.vaughan@icloud.com"; // email address to which the form data will be sent
$subject = "Contact Email";
$thanks_page = "/contact/thankyou.html"; 
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
$nam = $_POST["name"];
$ema = trim($_POST["email"]);
$org = trim($_POST["organisation"]);
$com = $_POST["comments"];
$loadtime = $_POST["loadtime"];
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) { 
$nam = stripslashes($nam);
$ema = stripslashes($ema);
$org = stripslashes($org);
$com = stripslashes($com);
}
$error_msg=array(); 

if (empty($nam) || !preg_match("~^[a-z\-'\s]{1,60}$~i", $nam)) { 
$error_msg[] = "The name field must contain only letters, spaces, dashes ( - ) and single quotes ( ' )";
}
if (empty($ema) || !filter_var($ema, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
$error_msg[] = "Your email must have a valid format, such as name@mailhost.com";
}
if (empty($org) || !preg_match("~^[a-z\-'\s]{1,60}$~i", $org)) { 
$error_msg[] = "The Organisation must contain only letters, spaces, dashes ( - ) and single quotes ( ' )";
}
$limit = 1000000000000000000000000000000000000;
if (empty($com) || !preg_match("/^[0-9A-Za-z\/-\s'\(\)!\?\.,]+$/", $com) || (strlen($com) > $limit)) { 
$error_msg[] = "Your message must contain only letters, digits, spaces and basic punctuation (&nbsp;'&nbsp;-&nbsp;,&nbsp;.&nbsp;)";
}
$totaltime = time() - $loadtime;
if($totaltime < 7) {
echo("<p>Please fill in the form before submitting!</p>");
echo '</ul>
<form method="post" action="', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], '">
<input placeholder="Your Name*" name="name" type="text"  id="name" value="'; if (isset($_POST["name"])) {echo $nam;}; echo '">
<input placeholder="Your Email Address*" name="email" type="email"  id="email"'; if (isset($_POST["email"])) {echo $ema;}; echo '">
<input placeholder="Your Organisation*" name="organisation" type="text" id="organisation" value="'; if (isset($_POST["organisation"])) {echo $org;}; echo '">
<textarea placeholder="Your Message" name="comments" rows="5" cols="50" id="comm">'; if (isset($_POST["comments"])) {echo $com;}; echo '</textarea>
<input type="hidden" name="loadtime" value="', time(), '">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;SEND" id="submit">
</form>';
exit;
}
if ($error_msg) {
echo '
<p>Unfortunately, your message could not be sent. The form as you filled it out is displayed below. Make sure each field is completed. Please address any issues listed below:</p>
<ul class="err">';
foreach ($error_msg as $err) {
echo '<li>'.$err.'</li>';
}
echo '</ul>
<form method="post" action="', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], '">
<input placeholder="Your Name*" name="name" type="text"  id="name" value="'; if (isset($_POST["name"])) {echo $nam;}; echo '">
<input placeholder="Your Email Address*" name="email" type="email"  id="email"'; if (isset($_POST["email"])) {echo $ema;}; echo '">
<input placeholder="Your Organisation*" name="organisation" type="text"  id="organisation" value="'; if (isset($_POST["organisation"])) {echo $org;}; echo '">
<textarea placeholder="Your Message" name="comments" rows="5" cols="50" id="comm">'; if (isset($_POST["comments"])) {echo $com;}; echo '</textarea>
<input type="hidden" name="loadtime" value="', time(), '">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;SEND" id="submit">
</form>';
exit();
} 
$email_body = 
"Name of sender: $nam\n\n" .
"Email of sender: $ema\n\n" .
"Organisaition: $org\n\n" .
"COMMENTS:\n\n" .
"$com" ; 
if  (!$error_msg) {
mail ($your_email, $subject, $email_body, "From: $nam <$ema>" . "\r\n" . "Reply-To: $nam <$ema>");
die ("Thank you. Your message has been sent to the appropriate person.");
exit();
}


$sendto = $_POST["email"]; // this is the email address collected form the form
$ccto = "jp.vaughan@icloud.com"; //you can cc it to yourself
$subjectCon = "Email Confirmation"; // Subject
$message = "the body of the email - this email is to confirm etc...";
$header = "From: auto-confirm@moibrahimfoundation.org\r\n";
// This is the function to send the email
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
mail($sendto, $subjectCon, $message, $header); 
}} 

?>
```

Comment: Check your server log & SMTP log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are exiting the code after sending the first email.

```
if  (!$error_msg) {
if (mail ($your_email, $subject, $email_body, "From: $nam <$ema>" . "\r\n" . "Reply-To: $nam <$ema>");
die ("Thank you. Your message has been sent to the appropriate person."); //you are exiting here
exit(); //additional exit here. the second email won't be sent if there is no error.
}


$sendto = $_POST["email"]; // this is the email address collected form the form
$ccto = "jp.vaughan@icloud.com"; //you can cc it to yourself
$subjectCon = "Email Confirmation"; // Subject
$message = "the body of the email - this email is to confirm etc...";
$header = "From: auto-confirm@moibrahimfoundation.org\r\n";
// This is the function to send the email
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
mail($sendto, $subjectCon, $message, $header);
```

should be

```
$success='';
if  (!$error_msg) {
    if (mail ($your_email, $subject, $email_body, "From: $nam <$ema>" . "\r\n" . "Reply-To: $nam <$ema>")){
        $success="Thank you. Your message has been sent to the appropriate person.";
    }else{
        $success="Your message cannot be sent";
    }
}


$sendto = $_POST["email"]; // this is the email address collected form the form
$ccto = "jp.vaughan@icloud.com"; //you can cc it to yourself
$subjectCon = "Email Confirmation"; // Subject
$message = "the body of the email - this email is to confirm etc...";
$header = "From: auto-confirm@moibrahimfoundation.org\r\n";
// This is the function to send the email
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
mail($sendto, $subjectCon, $message, $header);
die($success);
```

if your first mail is also not sending please check the mail configuration in your php.ini and verify that you can send mail through it.

Comment: Solved it myself...just do two mail functions..
if  (!$error_msg) {
    mail ($your_email, $subject, $email_body, "From: $nam <$ema>" . "\r\n" . "Reply-To: $nam <$ema>"); 

Obviously using the vars i had before
    mail($sendto, $subjectCon, $message, $header); 
    die ("Thank you. Your message has been sent to the appropriate person.");
    exit();
    }

Answer (score 0):

use this tool for checking ur mail is sending or not...also it will show all parameters of mail function...

[Test Tool](http://www.toolheap.com/test-mail-server-tool/)